# finding multiple documents with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

[this is what happens when I console.log()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BELz9.png)

[this is what happens when I return all documents with that id, I just get the first document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsN1F.png)

```
const followingUsers = await User.find({ _id: { $in: foundUser.followings } })

const getFeedData = async() => {

    for (let user of followingUsers) {


        for (let postId of user.posts) {

            console.log(postId)
        }
    }
}
```

**I'm running this code when I console.log(postId) it returns all the posts with that id, but when I try to retrieve all documents with that id it returns just one document**

Comment: `return await Post.findById(postId)` it returns ony the first document not all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findById` will only return one record or `null`, an ID is the _id field on each document in a collection, which is a unique value

`find` is the equivalent of a `where` command in SQL, it returns as many documents that match the query, or an empty array

passing `$in` as a query to `find` looks for an array of matching document for the user id's

so if you already know the document _id's, then `find` will return the ID's so long you have passed an array of valid `ObjectId`

```js
// (pretending these are real id's)
const arrayOfUserIds = [
  ObjectId("5af619de653438ba9c91b291"),
  ObjectId("5af619de653438ba9c91b293"),
  ObjectId("5af619de653438ba9c91b297")
]

const users = await User.find({ _id: { $in: arrayOfUserIds } })

console.log(users.length)

users.forEach((user, index) => {
 console.log(`${index} - `, user._id)
})

// => 3
// => 0 - ObjectId("5af619de653438ba9c91b291")
// => 1 - ObjectId("5af619de653438ba9c91b293")
// => 2 - ObjectId("5af619de653438ba9c91b297")
```